# CSS Styling not 'cascading'?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am updating someones site. Their markup selecting `<a>` tags is like this:

```
#wrapper a{color: red;}
```

Which is fine. But if I create a `<div>` within wrapper and give it the `<a>` tags my own styling eg:

```
.mydiv a{color: white;}
```

It simply doesnt work - the `color:white` in my `<div>` gets overwritten by the color:red in wrapper, even though the .mydiv css is located below the `#wrapper` css on my external style sheet. Whats more every other styling - background-color, border, etc - works fine!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

The selector with the `id` attribute is more specific than the selector with the `class` attribute (the former points to a single element but the latter points to multiple elements), so the selector with the `id` takes precedence over yours regardless of the order.

Your selector needs to be more specific in order to override the other selector:

```
#wrapper .mydiv a{color: white;}
```

Comment: Thanks thats done the trick - should have thought of that before

Answer (score 0):

The reason your CSS rule is being overwritten is because the priority of style rules depends largely on the specificity at which they're defined.

`.myClass a` is less specific than `#myID a`, as class selection implies a broader range of elements to be affected by the rule than does ID. To ensure that your rule takes precedence over the old one, simply use `#wrapper .mydiv a` as your selector, thereby enhancing the specificity of your rule to surpass that of the old one.